# Oil filter on my motorcycle is not coming off

Tags: motorcycle, oil-filter

Background: I own a Yamaha XJ6n. This is the first time I'm removing the filter. The last guy who owned this must have screwed it on reaaaal tight.

My oil filter is refusing to come off. This should be an easy removal, but it really isn't. I've bought an oil filter removal tool (something that fits around the oil filter that your wrench can slot into, same as the guy in this video here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Wv6gd7E5o2A) and it's actually slipping off the filter rather than the oil filter loosening. Any ideas? Is penetrating fluid okay to use? It wouldn't contaminate anything?

EDIT: I've already tried the screwdriver & hand-unscrewing route to no avail... this thing is really stuck!

ANOTHER EDIT: After being frustated, trying a few different tools, I think I'm going to just jbweld my removal tool onto the filter so that it stops slipping off 
(this is the removal tool btw
[image] 
)

Screw it. It was a £5 removal tool. My sanity is worth marginally more than that. I'll let you guys know what happens, thanks to everyone who took the time to answer thus far.

FINAL EDIT: Managed to get it off by jbwelding the socket to it. Even then - had to try 3 attempts: the first 2 times the epoxy cracked and went first! Mad. I think it was the screwdriver-in-the-side that deformed oil filer enough for the socket not to function properly. A heads up, there. I'll give a "accepted answer" to the guy with the most votes currently...

Comment: I think your solution was brilliant.  Answer your own question and award yourself the answer.  I would upvote it.  Well done!  You had the answer.  Cheers!   +1

Comment: Cheers @DucatiKiller. I appreciate that! At the same time, I appreciate the guys who took time out to give a suggestion in how to sort this out, so I'd like to acknowledge them in some way as well!

Comment: Indeed.  Contributing solutions to problems is giving.  We have a lot of givers here.  Cheers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It must not be the correct size for the filter I'd advise buying something like the CTA-2507.

[image]

This will grab the sides of the filter and works with a large number of different filters. I use one of these for any aftermarket filter that may not be the same size as the OE sized cups.

Alternatively you can use a large pair of channel locks as was suggested.

Comment: This is the *ultimate* tool for this job, requires almost no clearance, and simply never fails.   However, it costs money...  while a Craftsman phillips screwdriver hammered through the side costs almost nothing, and you can get it replaced for free after you abuse it to no end.   HOWEVER, if you choose to go the screwdriver *southern style* route, please please please wear gloves, because this can create some wicked sharp edges which you might be tempted in your sucess excitement to grab with bare hands.  Ask me how I know....

Comment: Cheers, Ben! I might try this... the tool I've tried is basically this only it's not variable in size. However now that it's the 14 flute version and started to slip, perhaps this 3 flute version might grip better.

Comment: @SteveRacer ... I've actually tried the screwdriver-hammered-in appoach already! it started cutting through the oil filter before the oil filter budged, and I then stopped pretty quick so that I could use something like ^^ this still...

Answer (score 4):

[image: My oil removing tool]

Fits on every known oil filter. Cheap and simple. And never slips. As harder it is tensioned, as harder it will grip it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! My fault, I forgot to mention that this oil filter is in a pretty awkward position, so I don't think this would be able to get the room to work... see vid.

Comment: Based upon the video link this device will not fit into the available space to be useful.

Answer (score 3):

If there's enough room around the filter and it's a cartridge type, you can actually stab it all the way through with a screwdriver or punch and use that as a lever to turn it.

If you don't want to do that, try to grab onto it with channel locks or vise grips. Remember that you're throwing the filter away so it doesn't matter if it's squished.

If it's an internal type, I'd use the same method as for any other bolt, heat and penetrating oil.

Comment: Based upon the video link in OP's question doing this would not work.  There is not enough space available to do it.  I've done this on cars where there is plenty of room but in this situation it's difficult to see how it could work.

Answer (score 1):

Bike filters are, frankly, a pain sometimes. The cup filter remover you posted should do the job, just be sure to use lots of leverage with a long pry bar or a piece of long pipe stuck on the end of your socket wrench.

The oil filter on my car, if it's stuck, can only be removed by the cup type filter and a bit of hitting a pry bar with a hammer, if its very stubborn.

Answer (score 1):

I had one like this and I just drove an old phillips screwdriver through it and unscrewed it.